# Groovy extension modules in Android?

Tags: java, android, groovy

I'm attempting to use Groovy for an Android project, and my first task is to get global extensions in place.

Intellisense works and things compile fine, but I get a runtime exception when it comes across my method

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method

I have the extension class listed in the extension file.

What needs to happen to ensure the extension is registered and used at runtime?

Edit: Seriously, whoever voted this down - where is the documentation on this stuff?  It's not like I didn't search for hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Start by looking at the information in the runtime exception. Also look for the documentation on running Groovy on Android, eg the jar files to include in the built APK.

Comment: The runtime exception was with the groovy language method lookup.  A 'use' block works fine but I want a "global use block".  The documentation on all of this is very, very thin.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=groovy%20on%20android finds lots of docs, including Groovy 2.4 release notes http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+2.4+release+notes , Android Support in the groovyc reference http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/tools-groovyc.html#section-android and the gradle plug-in https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin . Do they have big gaps?

Comment: The problem is not getting Groovy working on Android.  The problem is specifically getting custom Groovy class extension modules working (on Android).  But yeah, it's easy to gloss over everything I wrote, cherry pick two words, and make me look like an idiot.  Thank you for your helpful input.

Answer (score -1):

This project seems to have done it with success:
[SwissKnife on Github](https://github.com/Arasthel/SwissKnife)

It is using gradle for an Android library build. I would try to use those gradle build scripts as a template.

The key to registering an extension with the Groovy runtime is the presence of

**org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule**

unter **META-INF/services** in the library.

In the SwissKnife subproject it is located in the src/main/resources directory. That follows the standard convention used by the Gradle Groovy/Android plugin.

Comment: "under META-INF/service in the library" - where is the library? Have you tried this yourself?